# How do you clear the default changelist without altering your worktree in Perforce

Tags: perforce

By accident I reconciled all my work. I want to now keep my working tree as it is, but have perforce remove the changes from the default changelist. How do you clear the default pending changelist without affecting the files? I do not want to revert to the depot state.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If you don't want the changes in your default changelist (and presumably not in a numbered changelist), where do you want them?  If you have edited files in your local tree that differ from the ones on the Perforce server, they *should* be in a changelist.

Answer (score 2):

```
p4 revert -k //...
```

Note that this is a little dangerous because now you have local changes that Perforce doesn't know about -- they'll be silently missed when you submit (unless you do another reconcile), and a force sync may overwrite them.  If your changed files are open, Perforce can be a lot more intelligent about the fact that you've made changes to them -- schedule resolves when they change in the depot, be careful not to modify them when syncing, etc.